# Drupal 7 video player for stream

Tags: files

I'm using JW Player for playing video files and it's working great.

Is it possible to play video streams with this player?

I already have a rights to stream and link for a TV station. It's in this format: http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9090/stream.flv

How can I set this link for stream?

If you know some alternative player with possibility of live streaming, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWPlayer does streaming.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/hls-rtmp-live-streaming

I wasn't able to find a module that did this, but you can add this to your page, using the Full HTML text input:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jwplayer/jwplayer.js" ></script>
<div id="home-video">Loading the player</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("home-video").setup(
        {
            file: "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9090/stream.flv",
            height: 320,
            width: 640,
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried your code. I've changed the path src="http://www.mywebsite.com/sites/all/libraries/jwplayer/jwplayer.js" changed into HTML, but it's not appearing the player. When I've copied your code and changed the format into Full HTML and revert back into plain text, automatically deletes the code and only <div id="home-video">Loading the player</div> stayed there.

Comment: I t has to be FUll HTML. I tried this on my site and it works exactly right.

Comment: Scott, so you have Installed JW Player 7.x-1.0-alpha1 on your website and then you're adding your code, and after saving everything is working, right? Please add some details, 'cos I've tried with your code in FULL HTML and nothing appeared.

Comment: I have not installed any modules, I just added the player to my theme folder and went from there. If you try the module it wont let you use stream URL's.

Comment: Usually every code when I add into my wysiwyg editor first I enable plain text and then I switch into FULL HTML, but in this case when I'm switching your code into full html automatically deletes the code and only left this text "Loading the player". The editor does this when the script code is not right.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that. I'll try now to download the new JW Player from the official website and put into my theme folder, but first I'll disable the module.

Comment: OK, finally it works.I see some annoying bufferings while streaming, but on other website that uses Flow player it works better. I'll try with other version of JW Player, I hope will work better. Scott, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Comment: Hi, Scott. As I wrote before I've managed to play the stream with the newest version JW Player, but now when I've tried with version 5, it's not working. Is there any difference with the code for version 5? By the way what version do you use?

Comment: Here's a working demo of the stream, but from longtailvideo website http://bit.ly/1a1abIr. I didn't find a way to copy and edit the code from their website. Can you help me how to play this stream with JW Player version 5?

Comment: OK, now everything is ok. The problem comes from the paths. In the version 5, the two files are working when I've moved into the root folder.